# Using %.% in make file

Tags: makefile

I want to perform operations on a file inside the folder. There are 1000 folders and inside each folder there is one such file on which I have to perform some actions. Can I use the following? If not suggest me some method.

```
$(obj)/%.log : $(PATH)/%./%.c
```

Answer (score 3):

No.  GNU make only supports a single percent sign per target or prerequisite.  Any percents after the first are treated as literal `%` characters.

You can use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) for this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(obj)/%.log : $(PATH)/$$*./$$*.c
        run my command
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$$*` instead of `$$@`?